# WIX Order of execution with Custom Action

Tags: wix

I have a wix project that installs a web site, a couple of SQL Server databases and configures users etc.

Part of the install creates a database for the ASP.NET membership system using a Custom Action to execute aspnet_regsql.exe.

Another part of the installation then needs to execute a SQL script to create an initial user. The problem is that the script component is getting executed before the Custom Action has happened, so the references to membership tables and stored procedures in the script are invalid and the install fails.

This is part of my install file:

```
<Feature Id="Complete" Title="Darzi Web" Level="1" Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SiteIISConfig"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SQLConfig" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="InstallFiles" />
  <ComponentRef Id="WebConfigChanges" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SQLBootstrap" />
</Feature>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='RegSql'  After='InstallFiles'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I need a way to tell the installer to make sure that "SQLBootstrap" happens after "RegSql".

Any help would be gratefully received.

**EDIT**

This is the section that runs the Bootstrap SQL:

```
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
  <Component Id="SqlBoostrapComponent" Guid="CAAA1447-446F-4C1B-9239-812ABA5AF0FF" KeyPath="yes">

      <sql:SqlScript SqlDb='DarziAspNetDbDatabase' Id='Bootstrap' BinaryKey='Bootstrap' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' Sequence='1' />

  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>


<Binary Id='Bootstrap' SourceFile='Bootstrap.sql' />

<ComponentGroup Id="SQLBootstrap">
  <ComponentRef Id="SqlBoostrapComponent" />
</ComponentGroup>

</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the Sql scripts you run are using the inbuilt [sql actions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/sql_xsd_index.htm) You need to schedule the `InstallSqlData` action after your RegSql action:

```
<Custom Action="InstallSqlData" After="RegSql" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've updated my question above with the section that runs the SQL data script.  I've tried adding <Custom Action="Boostrap" After="RegSql"/> and "SQLBootstrap" but both give an error when building. "Unresolved reference to symbol 'CustomAction:Bootstrap"  I'm obviously doing something stupid here... :)

Comment: Did you actually try the code that I wrote? IIRC the InstallSqlData action is an inbuilt action that runs all the `<sql:SqlScript` elements which you can then order by the `Sequence` attribute. If you open the msi in Orca/InstEd and look at the ActionTable and see the full list of actions in your msi.

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't realise "InstallSqlData" was a special thing. My problem is, though, that I need to run most of the sql stuff before my RegSql Custom Action and then just the "SQLBootstrap" one after.

Comment: In that case your only option is to use the `sqlexportlonly` flag on the `aspnet_regsql.exe` and then include that in your installer. In-fact I would do it that way as your msi won't have to bundle or find the path to the `aspnet_regsql.exe` to execute and it will be much clearer to read as you can order your scripts all in one place.

Comment: Fantastic. Had no idea that was an option with aspnet_regsql. Thanks a million for your help. :)

Comment: No problems, happy to help!